# Ubuntu 16.04 freezing after some time of use

Tags: 16.04, system, error-handling

Sometimes, after a few hours of use, ubuntu freezes and I have to shut it down by hold the power button.

My laptop is Asus-X550

- Intel i5-3337U
- Nvidia Geforce 720m
- 8 GB of RAM

I tried to reinstall the same version and happened again. It looks like a problem with Xorg

https://pastebin.com/5eYH0Yky

The `/var/log/syslog` file after the system logged out itself (after waiting 3 or 4 minutes waiting without control of the mouse nor keyboard and without effect pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and logged in again.

Before starting to freeze, I launched Eclipse and only one tab in Chrome was opened at the same time.

Also, I had the top command running and there was nothing strange at the beginning of freezing, java (Eclipse) was taking about 0,7 % of RAM and was the most RAM consuming process. But after waiting those 3 minutes the XOrg service began to take more and more RAM, taking all of it until it logged out (Which is an outrage thing, given that I have 8 GB of RAM and was being used just before freezing about 2% of it)

Anyone know what is happening and how could I fix it?

---

UPDATE

output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 0.4 Loki  
Release:    0.4
Codename:   loki
```

output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux xBlackout 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the output of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a` thank you for helpnig us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek Done! Thank you for trying to help :)